# Updating child props when we change them in Parent Component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm having some trouble passing props in React class components.

```
<ProductCard allProducts={this.state.allProducts} />
```

Here, I am calling ProductCard component with allProduct prop in my parent Component. I am fetching data in componentDidMount and updating allProducts in my state using this.setState() but in ProductCard component, I am getting allProducts prop as empty array which is the initial value in parent component this.state.allProducts

But if I'm not wrong,  when I update the state then parent component should rerender (which, it is), and child component prop value should also change but that's not happening.

Parent component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import ProductCard from "../../Components/Products Card/ProductCard"

export default class SubCategory extends Component {

constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
        allProducts:[]
    }
}

componentDidMount = () => {

    let productData = []

    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        productData.push({
            productName:`Product ${i+1}`,
            price:"9999" 
        })
    }

    this.setState({allProducts:productData})
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <ProductCard allProducts={this.state.allProducts} name={this.state.name} />
        </>
    )
}
}
```

Child Component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ProductCard extends Component {

constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        allProducts:[]
    }
}

componentDidMount= () => {
    this.setState({allProducts:this.props.allProducts})
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
           ...
        </>
    )
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, post the parent component's code too.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Preferably as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). There is simply no way to diagnose this based on what's shown here.

Comment: Inside the `ProductCard` where are you checking the value of `allProducts`? Add that too.

Comment: I need to take prop value and set it to `ProductCard` state. But I need to change the prop in parent component.
I am setting state in componentDidMount in `ProductCard`.

Comment: @SuryaMahla - Add the code of `ProductCard`.

Comment: @SuryaMahla check it [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/black-dawn-enczk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @Mashiro I am trying to do the same thing, I want to store the prop value in child component's state but it shows empty array.

Answer (score 0):

In your child component try changing your constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        allProducts:[]
    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.allProducts.length > 0 ? (
          <ProductCard
            allProducts={this.state.allProducts}
            name={this.state.name}
          />
        ) : null}
      </>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I've tried it, it still gives empty array. I think I need to check if props are updated in child component and then re-set the state with new updated props. 
Am I thinking in the right way?

Comment: or you can only render the `ProductCard` component when your array has some products.

Comment: Yes, this approach will also work. I made it work by checking in my child component when my props get changed by comparing old props and new props and then storing the updated prop in child component's state.

Comment: @SuryaMahla - Okay, you can mark this as the answer as your issue is solved.